# Why is the "NEXT" button greyed out when trying to edit a Google Cloud Function?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

Right now, in a GCP Cloud Function I am unable to edit a function that I was previously able to.

[image: greyed-out]

If I'm quick, I can click it before it disables, which works, but I need to edit the environment variables on this page first. I know I can use the `gcloud cli`, but I would like to edit them in the Cloud Console.

I'm an owner, and a Cloud functions admin, so there shouldn't be a permissions issue. Also, I can successfully create a new cloud function, I just can't edit or copy this one.

Comment: @JohnMichaelGelilio I'm on the edit page

Comment: Did you use an inline editor or zip or cloud repository when you deployed your cloud function?

Comment: Try to use incognito mode or other browser.

Comment: @JohnMichaelGelilio I've used the inline editor and I've deployed from a local repo via the command line. I'm currently able to deploy from the command line. Also, I can click NEXT quickly after the page loads, but before the button is disabled and get to the next page.

Comment: No dice in incognito or in another browser. My coworker is also an owner and having the same issue.

Comment: Then, contact support from your console, or you can raise your issue in public issue tracker https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers#trackers-list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was an error on the GCP. It has been since patched.

If you run into errors like this in the future, make a ticket on their public ticket tracker.

https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers#trackers-list